# Need To Generate New Random Numbers For Each Sed Substitution Used In "While Loop"

Tags: bash, function, for-loop, sed, while-loop

I'm using sed to substitute a random 10 digit string of numbers for a certain field in a file, which I can successfully do.  However, the same random 10 digit string of numbers are used for each substitution sed performs which is unacceptable in this case.  I need a new random 10 digit string of numbers for every substitution sed performs.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
random_number()
    {
    for i in {1}; do tr -c -d 0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 10; done
    }

while read line
    do
        sed -E "s/[<]FITID[>][[:digit:]]+/<FITID>$(random_number)/g"
    done<~/Desktop/FITIDTEST.QFX
```

Here's a sample of what the original FITIDTEST.QFX file looks like:

```
                <FITID>1266821191

                <FITID>1267832241

                <FITID>1268070393

                <FITID>1268565193

                <FITID>1268882385

                <FITID>1268882384
```

And here is the output after executing the script:

```
                <FITID>4270240286

                <FITID>4270240286

                <FITID>4270240286

                <FITID>4270240286

                <FITID>4270240286

                <FITID>4270240286
```

I need those 10 digit numbers to be different for each  field.  I thought the "while loop" would force sed to call the **random_number()** function each time but apparently it's called once and the value is stored and used repeatedly.  Is there anyway to avoid that?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` is replacing all the lines with matching pattern not just one line hence at the end of loop you are seeing same number in replacement.

You can use:

```
while read line; do
    sed -E "/<FITID>/s/<FITID>[[:digit:]]+/<FITID>$(random_number)/" <<< "$line"
done < ~/Desktop/FITIDTEST.QFX > _tmp_
```

**Output:**

```
cat _tmp_

<FITID>9974823224
<FITID>1524680591
<FITID>7433495381
<FITID>6642730759
<FITID>9653629434
<FITID>1325816974
```

Comment: I still need to execute substitution for EVERY match but I just need every match to be substituted with a different random 10 digit number.  Your solution appears to only substitute the first match with a random 10 digit number.

Comment: Your updated command worked, thank you!  So if I understand this correctly, the "Here String" (<<<) is feeding sed one line at time and by adding: <FITID> before /s/<FITID> tells sed to execute on each line which in turn calls the $(random_number) function each time and generates a new random number?

Comment: Yes you summed it very well, that is exactly how it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { srand() }
{
    sub(/[0-9]+/,sprintf("%010d",rand()*10000000000))
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<FITID>3730584119
<FITID>1473036092
<FITID>8390375691
<FITID>6700634479
<FITID>8379256766
<FITID>6583696062

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<FITID>7844627153
<FITID>0141034890
<FITID>9714288799
<FITID>0911892354
<FITID>8916456168
<FITID>4187598430
```